# Conditional expectation of one random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable whose probability density function is
$$
f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \alpha^2xe^{-\alpha x} &   if  & x > 0 \\
             \\ 0&  otherwise 
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$
With $\alpha >0$. Calculate $E(X|X<1)$.

I know that by definition, I have
$$
E(X|X<1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x \cdot P(X|X<1) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}x \cdot \frac{P(X=x_k \land X<1 )}{P(X<1)}dx
$$
Is ok if i change the limits of the integral and put this?
$$
E(X|X<1)=\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot \frac{P(X<1 )}{P(X<1)}dx=\frac{1}{2}
$$
It confuses me a bit that the condition is on the same random variable. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're conditioning on an event like $\{X<1\}$ you're essentially using your given pdf $f$ which is originally supported on $(0,\infty)$ to generate a "new" pdf $f_E$ that's supported on $E=(0,1)$. This can be accomplished by considering $f_E(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)dt}$ for $x\in E$ and $f_E(x)=0$ elsewhere. So $$E(X|X<1)=\int_0^1xf_{E}(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is
$$\operatorname{E}[X \mid X < 1] = \frac{\int_{x=0}^1 x f_X(x) \, dx}{\int_{x=0}^1 f_X(x) \, dx}.$$  You cannot write $Pr[X = x_k \wedge X < 1]$ because first of all, you did not define $x_k$, and second, it would need to depend on the variable of integration $x$.  Then even if you did write $\Pr[X = x \wedge X < 1]$, this is problematic because $X$ has a density, not a probability mass function.  Fourth, even if you ignore all of the above, the events $X = x$ and $X < 1$ are not independent.